# Кто нибуть подскажет статью на русском по Gmagick

Tags: php

Добра всем. Кто нибуть сталкивался с классом Gmagick. Меня интресует статья на русском. А в частности как уменьшить изображение до определенного размера, как резать нормально изображение, как накладывать одно на другое. И как Уменьшить качество изображения.

[Оф доки на инглише и без примеров](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.gmagick.php)

Comment: там половина на русском, остальную половину уже можно догадаться после изучения первой.

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=php+Gmagick+%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA